# Spark not detecting all CPU cores

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I have a cluster running Spark with 4 servers each having 8 cores. Somehow the master is not detecting all available cores. It is using 18 out of 32 cores:

[image]

I have not set anything relating to the no. of cores in any spark conf file (at least not that I am aware of)

I am positive each cluster member has the same no. of cores (8):

[image]

Is there a way to make Spark detect/use the other cores as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found it but still it is somewhat unclear:

One node that was only contributing 1 out of 8 cores was having this setting turned on in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh:

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
```

Commenting it out did the trick for that node. Spark will grab all cores by default. (same goes for memory)

But... on the other node with only 1 core this setting was not activated, but still Spark did not grab 8 cores untill I specifically told it to:

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
```

But at least it is grabbing all resources now.